# Determining projection of Texas county shapefile?

Tags: coordinate-system, extents, united-states

I have a Shapefile of San Jacinto County in Texas.  It thinks it is NAD83 UTM Zone 15N, but the dataset isn't jiving with any other dataset.

Max X: 1,073,721   Max Y: 11,223,970
Min X: 895,728      Min Y: 11,013,769

I don't usually work with datasets from this part of the world, so I don't know which projections are in common use.  Anyone who is familiar with the area know what projection these extents might fit?

This is the county I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinates are rather high, so I made a first guess at ft-US units.

`EPSG:32165 NAD83 / BLM 15N (ftUS)` does a good job:

[image]

Comment: That looks great, I'll have to try it at home tonight.